# router stops allowing new wifi connections, but existing connections are unaffected

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

This issue happens occasionally, and only a router reset seems to fix it.  I will try to connect from a device that was off or not connected, e.g. laptop, cell phone, and the connection will fail.  The router is up and running - other devices with existing wifi connections continue to work, but no new devices may connect.  A reset on the router resolves the issue, until next time.  The router is an ASUS RT-AC86U running the latest firmware (2.250).  The issue has occurred with this firmware as well as the previous.  Thanks.

Comment: The issue has occurred with this firmware as well as the previous.    .... I suggest now doing a hard reset of the router back to factory specs.  Set up wireless profiles and test.

Comment: A router being 3 years old wouldn't explain this behavior.  I would agree.  Perform a factory reset, this will wipe whatever configuration setting, is causing this behavior more than likely.

Comment: Have you checked the manual, https://dlsvr04.asus.com/pub/ASUS/wireless/RT-AC86U/E13067_RT_AC86U_manual.pdf , for any setting restricting the number of connections?